# Multiple PlaceAutoCompleteFragment opens when clicked on it very quickly

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api

I am using Google's PlaceAutoCompleteFragment in a recent project that I am currently working on. When I click on the PlaceAutoCompleteFragment very quickly it open multiple overlays on my app which is really annoying. how can I prevent it from opening multiple overlays? My code for the fragment is given below:

```
if (autocompleteFragment == null) {
        autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocompletehome_fragment);
}

autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            try {
                Log.i("esty", "Place: " + place.getName());



            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("esty", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.e("esty", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try a hack to solve this problem.
Put a on click listener on the whole fragment and use multi click blocker to pass the click event once.

Refer to the below solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23103227/4901098

Comment: PlaceAutoCompleteFragment doesn't have an onclicklistener. but your solution may have given me an idea. Gonna use PlaceAutoComplete Intent Builder to implement this solution.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this is a bug in [PlaceAutocompleteFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlaceAutocompleteFragment) (and [SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)). Thank you for bringing it to our attention. We'll look at fixing this in an upcoming release.

Comment: Damn now I have to use the PlaceAutoComplete intent builder. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Same problem with the intent builder PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY.