# Preventing the same request from being sent simultaneously by Volley

Tags: java, android, queue, android-volley, request-queueing

I'm developing a general purpose library for Android apps and I'm using Volley to send requests over the network.
2 issues that came from the same problem: the user clicks the `Button` several times and the request is queued the # of times the user clicked the `Button` (which points to the same user XP problem).

I wish to tackle the problem on two issues in the client side of things:

- UI - general purpose button that has a timer threshold on click, so
  the user cannot click the `Button` too much times. This is and example
  of an implementation:
  [How to avoid multiple button click at same time in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971484/how-to-avoid-multiple-button-click-at-same-time-in-android)
- Volley as a Rest Client should hold the necessary information in order to deal with multiple requests that comes from the same operation.

How can I use Volley in order to not queue the same request twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I use Volley in order to not queue the same request twice?

Volley has no methods to interact with its `RequestQueue` (other than `add()`, `cancelAll()` and `finish()`).

You could use reflection to access the `mCurrentRequests` field (and compare your `Request` with the queued `Request`s), which i do not recommend.

You could just add your queued requests to a `WeakHashMap` (with the `Request` as the key) and check your new requests for equality (based on your implementation) with the key set.

For example:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue;
WeakHashMap<StringRequest, String> queuedRequests;

// ...

private boolean addRequestToQueue(StringRequest request, String tag) {
    for(StringRequest queuedRequest : queuedRequests.keySet()) {
        if(tag.equals(queuedRequest.getTag())) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    request.setTag(tag);
    requestQueue.add(request);
    queuedRequests.put(request, tag);

    return true;
}
```