# Multi touch button

Tags: button, touch

Is there any easy way to build a multi touch button? I build my first simple app and you need to click as fast as possible. Until now the speed is limited pecause you cant use multible fingers to click.

Answer (score 0):

**As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32819622/7044457) :**

You have to use:

```
public abstract class OnOneOffClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final long MIN_CLICK_INTERVAL=600;

private long mLastClickTime;

public static boolean isViewClicked = false;


public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);

@Override
public final void onClick(View v) {
   long currentClickTime=SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
   long elapsedTime=currentClickTime-mLastClickTime;

   mLastClickTime=currentClickTime;

   if(elapsedTime<=MIN_CLICK_INTERVAL)
       return;
   if(!isViewClicked){
       isViewClicked = true;
       startTimer();
   } else {
       return;
   }
   onSingleClick(v);        
 }
/**
 * This method delays simultaneous touch events of multiple views.
 */
private void startTimer() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                isViewClicked = false;
        }
    }, 600);

 }

}
```