# How to put a delay like 2 seconds after a button is clicked?

Tags: android, database, android-studio-3.0

My code is using 'case and break' example

```
                    case R.id.student:

                    showMessage("Student");

                    Intent std = new Intent(Home.this, student.class);

                    startActivity(std);

                    break;
```

Comment: case R.id.student:
                        showMessage("Student");
                        Intent std = new Intent(Home.this, student.class);
                        startActivity(std);
                        break;

Comment: I know I must use runnable or handler but how? Help me pls guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
switch (menuButton.getId()) {
        case R.id.student:
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showMessage("Student");
                    Intent std = new Intent(Home.this, student.class);
                    startActivity(std);
                }
            }, 2000);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: How to implement that ? 

public void onItemClick(CircleMenuButton menuButton) {
                switch (menuButton.getId()) {
                    case R.id.student:
                        showMessage("Student");
                        Intent std = new Intent(Home.this, student.class);
                        startActivity(std);
                        break;

Comment: @A.Garcia happy to help you. you may also accept my answer as right if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Using Runnable:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        // TO DO
    }
};
```

Using Handler:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TO DO
            }
        }, 1000);
```

In Your case it is like:

```
        switch (menuButton.getId()) {
            case R.id.student:
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        showMessage("Student");
                        Intent std = new Intent(Home.this, student.class);
                        startActivity(std);
                    }
                }, 1000);

                break;

        }
```

Comment: How to implement that ? 

public void onItemClick(CircleMenuButton menuButton) {
                switch (menuButton.getId()) {
                    case R.id.student:
                        showMessage("Student");
                        Intent std = new Intent(Home.this, student.class);
                        startActivity(std);
                        break;

Comment: Check my Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void onClick(View view) {
        int viewId = view.getId();
        if (viewId == R.id.btn_cherry) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do what you want after 1000 miliseconds
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A countdown timer can be used which lies in the object class as follows

```
 new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

this will start a timer for 2 seconds and you can handle your desired events in the ontick and onfinish block .

you can further refer to android official documentation

[countdown timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: Where can I put this case R.id.student:

                    showMessage("Student");

                    Intent std = new Intent(Home.this, student.class);

                    startActivity(std);

                    break;...using that?

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you have clicked a button at second x (startTime) now you need to enable action performed by button on x+2 second and again for next click x+2+2, for that

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
int seconds=difference/1000; //(this will change milisecond to second 
required value)
if(seconds>2){
//do task
}else{
return; //do not do task or return 
}
// this can be done for one or more than one switches at same time to avaiod multiple click of a button or clicking multiple button at short interval of time
```

[prevent rapid click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819477/how-to-prevent-rapid-double-click-on-a-button)