# Button events occur twice when pressed fast

Tags: android, button

On click on button call event or execute its corresponding method as many as times when pressed very fast?what is the best approach to handle this in android?

Comment: check this out...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534369/avoid-button-multiple-rapid-clicks

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand. Explain what you did, explain what actually happened, and then explain what you wanted to happen. Use more words. It might be useful to ask a friend to help you write the question in clear English.

Comment: Actually its a form and when user press the submit button entry gets saved my app users are complaining of same entries punched from app and i have used the above approach in a simple way by taking a variable of time interval and if time difference between successive punches is less than 2 second i am simply returning but still i am facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

on_tap is a common event I never had a problem using for this.
You can "tap" as fast as you can, and the event should be raised every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick(View v) { 
MultiClickPreventer.preventMultiClick(v); 
//your op here 
}
```

...

```
public class MultiClickPreventer { 
private static final long DELAY_IN_MS = 500;

public static void preventMultiClick(final View view) {
    if (!view.isClickable()) {
        return; 
    } 
    view.setClickable(false);
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            view.setClickable(true);
        } 
    }, DELAY_IN_MS);
}
```

}

Comment: used this approach sir but didn't work for me the events get stored in queue  before clickable is set to false

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, it is possible for multiple button click events to be enqueued before the first click event is handled in `onClick()`, so simply calling `setClickable(false)` or `setEnabled(false)` won't always work.

However, even though you can have multiple events queued up, they will always be handled on the same thread, which means there will always be a **first** click event.

Store a `boolean` of your own and only perform your `onClick()` actions the first time.

```
private boolean firstEvent = true;

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (firstEvent) {
        firstEvent = false;
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: but i have multiple buttons in my form and setting a boolean value for each of them is not a good practice.

Comment: but i show alert dialogs  and have around 3 to 4 buttons also do you think its a good idea to have separate variable set for all of them and setting them all back to true if there is any network connection  issue while  making network call on submitting ?

Comment: If you need special behavior for your buttons, you're going to have to write code to create that special behavior.