# Prevent touch within small time interval in Android

Tags: android, events, touch

I am facing an issue if user touches multiple button within a small time interval(less than 1 second). I want only one of them to be executed. Similar issue with touch and swipe as well.

I have tried below solutions:

1. Use a boolean flag and set inside onClickListener. If this flag is then directly return from onClickListener. This approach does not work for me as it is not very deterministic to decide correct place to unset the flag.
2. Check time difference between two consecutive onClicListener and ignore 2nd if it is less than some threshold value. Issue with this approach that it is not very deterministic and threshold may vary for devices. Also if I keep it very high and device will appear to be very slow.

What I want is 2nd touch to not even register if first touch onClickListener is not completed. Are there other ways to control the touch events in Android?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a debouncer / debounced click listener. You can find implementation details by searching using these terms, with some examples here - https://medium.com/swlh/android-click-debounce-80b3f2e638f3 - and here - [Avoid button multiple rapid clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534369/avoid-button-multiple-rapid-clicks).