# How to send a event from one process to another process within the app

Tags: android

Scenario:

- I have an activity `AndroidProcessActivity`
- I launch a new Activity `NewProcessActivity` from
  `AndroidProcessActivity` but this is a different process than previous app
- Both activities are within te app

Question:

- Now how to send an event from `AndroidProcessActivity` to
  `AndroidProcessActivity`
- Is this possible

```
    <activity
    android:name=".game.NewProcessActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:process=":testScreen"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

***Question is about Inter process communication***

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano .... The question is not about launching a new activity ... its about IPC(interprocess communication)

Comment: Are you sure your activities are running on different processes?

Comment: Did you try BroadcastReceiver? Create one with a custom IntentFilter to catch the event

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano ... Yes it is a different process ... I have added a snippet of the manifest on how it is declared in the manifest

Comment: @TamHuynh ... I have tied this in the past it was not working ... let me double check on this

Comment: Yes, I think `BroadcastReceiver` works because the event goes through the system by `Intent` and `IntentFilter`, even the communication between the Notification and the current app still uses this process to send the event

Comment: @TamHuynh ... I tried this ... it doesn't work ... May be it works if they are two separate apps. I tried my own solution from this article https://medium.com/p/766257cac709#7814 ... it's not working ... U can check once with  sample .... I have added the snippet in question on how to declare process in manifest

Answer (score 0):

Normally a new activity runs in the same process (that is the default). So you can simply call a member function of `NewProcessActivity` from activity `AndroidProcessActivity` and vice-versa.

For example you can use a singleton variable inside `NewProcessActivity` so you have an object when you want to call a member function. But be aware activities can be [launched multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077728/how-to-prevent-the-activity-from-loading-twice-on-pressing-the-button).

There is the [process](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#proc) and [multiprocess](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#multi) property of `<activity>`. Those might result in an activity being run on a separate process.

Because everything (also threads) are called processes on Linux I am not sure if it's possible to simply call methods on this new process from the main process. I recommand to simply try it out and if it works you have to use Java [synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean) to make everything thread safe.

If it's not possible (that is what I expect) you have to use IPC:

- use the start `Intent` to pass parameters to the activity
- use [broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) to send messages in both directions (do this if you have to transfer simple values only)
- If you have a complicated API you have to create your own service and bind it (see [bound services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services)). You have to write an .aidl file. This is how IPC is normally done on Android.
- If you have native code or you want max. performance you can do native Linux IPC. Those could be local sockets or shared memory for example. But this might require root and it's unusual.