# Android: Fast button presses results in multiple instances of intent

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-intent

Currently I'm experiencing a bug where if the user quickly taps a button, the intent that the button is attached to will fire off multiple times, resulting in a stack of that intent that will need to be back traced through again. How can I avoid this or remedy this?

Thanks 
~k

This is inside of the onClickListener. I set the boolean value here, then I unset it at the end of the process.

```
        if(!isDating)
        {
            intent.setClass(context, EventDate.class);
            isDating = true;
            ((TabGroupActivity)
            context).startChildActivity("EventDate",intent);
        }
```

Comment: well, you can define a boolean var,like `isClicked`, when click make the `isClciked` to true, until you finish the click process, set it to false.

Comment: "the intent that the button is attached to" - What does that mean? You can't 'attach' an `Intent` to a `Button` - that makes no sense.

Comment: Can you pls put the code to launch the intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found a better solution!

by setting the onClickListener(null); then recreating it onResume, it bypasses having to use flags and what not.

!k

Comment: Really? Even with several buttons? Wouldn't that get cluttered?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the flags for the intent like

```
intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
```

You can also set this flag via AndroidManifest.xml file in the Application section. Prefer this method over above one.

[Updating launchMode using the Manifest file](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode)

Hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 3):

If i had a dime for this bug my QA filed I would be pretty rich if not a millionaire :P There are only so much one can do. Based on your implementation you could try a few things.

1. As already mentioned, use a boolean. Set it to true once you click it and check this boolean if the button is clicked again. Set it to false once you are done.
2. Use a progress dialog in case its a long activity like receiving data in your next activity before it displays. This also gives a hint to the user, that something is happening and he need not worry.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

it fixes the problem